# Sort hash key. Is fetch order is fixed?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two object hashes like these below.

```js
a[13] = obj2
a[25] = obj3
a[35] = obj4
a[54] = obj1

sortKey[13] = {order:2}
sortKey[25] = {order:3}
sortKey[35] = {order:4}
sortKey[54] = {order:1}
```

Then I fetch like this:

```js
for (var key in a) {
  console.log(a[key]) // it shows obj2, obj3, obj4, obj1
}
```

I want to show obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4.

So, can I sort `a` by `sortkey`?
Is it possible to sort hash?

Comment: should `sortKey[45] = {order:1}` be `sortKey[54]`?

Comment: To have sorted list of element I would rather use array instead of object. Object is unpredictable when it comes to keys order.

Comment: @Nick Parsons ah yes that's my mystake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to change order of key-value pairs in javascript object. Integer-like keys will be returned first in ascending order, then string key in insertion order, and then symbol keys in insertion order

But, you can attach a custom iterator to the object that will take control over how iterators (`for..of`) will return values if applied on this object. In the simplest form without handy abstractions it will look like this:

```js
const obj1 = { name: 'obj1' }
const obj2 = { name: 'obj2' }
const obj3 = { name: 'obj3' }
const obj4 = { name: 'obj4' }

const a = {}
a[13] = obj2
a[25] = obj3
a[35] = obj4
a[54] = obj1

const sortKey = {}
sortKey[13] = {order:2}
sortKey[25] = {order:3}
sortKey[35] = {order:4}
sortKey[54] = {order:1}

a[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  const e = Object
    .entries(this)
    .sort((a,b) => sortKey[a[0]].order - sortKey[b[0]].order)

  let _c = 0

  return {
    next: () => {
      return e[_c] ? { value: e[_c++][1], done: false } : { done: true }
    },
  }
}

for (const v of a) {
  console.log(v)
}
```

Comment: I understood the basic idea that hash doesn't keep the order. I will use some work aroundway. Your example also helps me so much.

Answer (score 0):

Keys will be returned in an unpredictable sequence.  You *can* retrieve a list of keys, sort that list, and then retrieve the values using that sorted list.  That's the only way to do it when using a hash table.  Note that you are consuming storage both for the hash table and the list.